# EF Core.Tools not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function or program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

After installing EntityFrameworkCore.Tools in Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019 I receive an error message in console that te package manager console cant find the file.

Went over the .nuget folder & the packages folder for the project & deleted all instances of .Tools. Then the error diappears, but as soon as I install .Tools again the error appear.

Seem to be a problem with powershell pathing? But I am not sure how to fix or troubleshoot this.

This is the error message:

"The term 'C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\SamuraiApp\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.2.2.6\tools\init.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."